# Android Layout Incompatible Type FrameLayout inside DrawerLayout Widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, drawerlayout

I want to add a admob banner in my application, but I get an error. I think this is Framelayout, but I got a message that this is a view.

```
FrameLayout bannerMainLayout = ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.banner_main);
```

I got messages: 
Incompatible types. 
Required android.widget.FrameLayout 
Found: android.view.View

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </FrameLayout>

    <!--Main content-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/banner_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Navigation Drawer-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please help, how to resolve this error?

Comment: `DrawerLayout` can have only **two childs**, one is main container and other one is drawer container. In your case it's having 3 `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` & `NavigationView`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede so, do you have solution for this issue? I need to add admob banner in this main activity

Comment: Try removing `FrameLayout` having id of `containerView` from xml file, if you're using it in Activity, try adjusting it in your `RelativeLayout` or find some workaround for it. Main thing is to have only two in `DrawerLayout`. This might be the issue.